# Can I prevent the browser to suggest the stored password in a change password dialog?

Tags: html, forms

I have developed a "change password" form where the user shall enter the current password, new password and repeat the new password. The form itself is easy to create, but I haven't found a way to prevent the browser to suggest the internally stored password. I have used the attribute `autocomplete="new-password"` (without it the stored password is automatically inserted in the password input).

But the browser still suggest the stored password. Can this be solved?

See image below for user "test" (Swedish Firefox browser):

[image]

The code is showed below:

```
<html class="" lang="sv">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Change password</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
    <div class="container">
        <form class="" action="changepwd.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <h3>Change password</h3>
            <p class="">Enter old and new password below</p>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="current_pwd">Current password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="current_pwd" name="current_pwd" type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
            </div>
                
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="new_pwd">New password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="new_pwd" name="new_pwd" type="password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="repeat_pwd">Repeat password:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="repeat_pwd" name="repeat_pwd" type="password" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            
            <div class="text-center py-3">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit btn-primary">Update password</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `autocomplete="off"`. I know its probably not ideal, but it should work.

Comment: @bobsfriend That will put the stored password into the password input :-/

Comment: do your dev tools say that the `autocomplete='new-password'`?